# Indenting when using ()

Tags: indentation

When I use braces `(`, the indenting is screwed up. Filetype is not set (but it's the same if I set it to e.g. txt). Here's what I type:

```
foo<CR>bar<CR>foo (<CR>bar
```

Here's how it looks like in vim

```
foo
bar
foo (
        bar
```

Why does the second `bar` get indented? I have auto indent and cindent in my `.vimrc`.

Here's the output of `:scriptnames`:

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim
  3: ~/.vimrc
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim80/filetype.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/dockerfile.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin.vim                                                        
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim                                                          
  8: ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim                                                             
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim80/ftoff.vim                                                           
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syntax.vim                                                   
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim                                                  
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim                                                 
 13: ~/.vim/colors/peaksea.vim                                                                
 14: ~/.vim/plugin/Bclose.vim                                                                 
 15: ~/.vim/plugin/NERD_tree.vim                                                              
 16: ~/.vim/plugin/a.vim                                                                      
 17: ~/.vim/plugin/conque_gdb.vim                                                             
 18: ~/.vim/autoload/conque_gdb.vim                                                           
 19: ~/.vim/autoload/conque_term.vim                                                          
 20: ~/.vim/plugin/conque_term.vim                                                            
 21: ~/.vim/plugin/toggle.vim                                                                 
 22: ~/.vim/plugin/yankstack.vim                                                              
 23: ~/.vim/autoload/yankstack.vim                                                            
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/gundo/plugin/gundo.vim                                                     
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/autoloclist.vim                                 
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/balloons.vim                                    
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/checker.vim                                     
 28: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/cursor.vim                                      
 29: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/highlighting.vim                                
 30: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/loclist.vim                                     
 31: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/modemap.vim                                     
 32: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/notifiers.vim                                   
 33: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/registry.vim                                    
 34: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic/signs.vim                                       
 35: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/plugin/syntastic.vim                                             
 36: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/util.vim                                      
 37: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/SyntaxFolds.vim                                           
 38: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/a.vim                                                     
 39: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/filebrowser.vim                                           
 40: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/imaps.vim                                                 
 41: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/plugin/remoteOpen.vim                                            
 42: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim                                          
 43: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/gzip.vim                                                     
 44: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/logiPat.vim                                                  
 45: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/manpager.vim                                                 
 46: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/matchparen.vim                                               
 47: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim        
 48: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/rrhelper.vim                                                 
 49: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/spellfile.vim                                                
 50: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tarPlugin.vim                                                
 51: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/tohtml.vim                                                   
 52: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim                                            
 53: /usr/share/vim/vim80/plugin/zipPlugin.vim                                                
 54: ~/.vim/bundle/syntastic/autoload/syntastic/log.vim
```

Comment: Some info that will certainly be needed to answer this is `:scriptnames`, that will tell you (and us) what syntax files have been loaded.

Comment: @grochmal I added this information.

Comment: check your indent settings. Looks like cindent or something similar is on. also try to come up with a minimal reproducible example, that does not include all your plugins.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Yes, cindent is on. Is that a problem?

Comment: @pfnuesel apparently yes. You don't want C like indenting in your text document, do you?

Answer (score 2):

Before I was using

```
set cindent
```

in my `.vimrc`. If I understand correctly, this turns on `cindent` for all filetypes. If I do not specify, it will only be turned on for `cpp` files, which is what I want. So removing `set cindent` from my `.vimrc` did the trick.

Comment: [`'smartindent'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27smartindent%27) is a bit, well smarter when it comes to indenting. You may give that a try as well.

Comment: I turned off `smartindent` at some point, can't remember the reason though. I might give it a try again. So far I wasn't very lucky with indenting in `vim`.